# Where can I get projections of the population by income level and age (such as population by income percentile) in a US county through 2040?

Tags: data-request, economics, population, income

For example, a long-term projection of the population in [Fulton County, GA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fulton_County,_Georgia) (not this one specifically, just a random county I picked) with the number of people age 65+ earning more than $100,000, the number of people age 65+ earning more than $200,000, etc. I know the error bars will be huge on this, especially that many years out, but I have to ignore that for now. It doesn't have to be those exact income levels, but I'm looking for some measure of the projected income distribution by age or age bracket.

Comment: I'm guessing census.gov and googling were both unhelpful?

Comment: @barrycarter Correct. The US Census has [population projections](https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/popproj.html), but these do not contain income. For data sources that do have income, sometimes even by county, e.g. the [CPS](https://www.census.gov/data/tables/time-series/demo/income-poverty/cps-pinc.html) or the [BEA](https://www.bea.gov/data/income-saving/personal-income-county-metro-and-other-areas), they don't have projections, as far as I can find.

Comment: https://www2.census.gov/library/publications/1998/compendia/smadb97-98.pdf is the only thing google found (I'm sure you've seen it)... If you google "personal income projections" (in quotes), you'll find some state level documents, but there doesn't appear to be a single unified source. data.gov also turns up very little useful

Comment: @barrycarter Thanks, I may have to look at individual state-level sources, where they're available. Table B-8 in that Census link contains the personal income projections, but they only go through 2010 (which isn't surprising, since the publication itself is from 1998).